# Define custom comparator at run time for std::set

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need help on being able to define a custom std::set comparator at run time. I know how to define a basic comparator with fixed value. I am really stuck on how to do it at run time. I am running Visual Studio 2010, if that helps.

Below is my code:

```
#include <set>

struct CustomComp
{
    CustomComp():m_tolerance(0.1){}

    //Always assume tolerance >= 0.0
    CustomComp(double const &tolerance):m_tolerance(tolerance){}

    /*Only return true when the two number are sufficiently apart from each other*/
    bool operator()(double const &n1, double const &n2)
    {
        double diff = n1 - n2;
        if(diff < 0.0 && std::abs(diff) > m_tolerance) return true;
        if(diff > 0.0 && std::abs(diff) > m_tolerance) return false;

        return false;
    }
private:
    double m_tolerance;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /*This works */
    std::set<double, CustomComp> aaa;
    aaa.insert(0.0);
    aaa.insert(0.2);
    aaa.insert(0.3);
    aaa.insert(10.0);

    /*What I really want*/
    double tol = GetToleranceFromUser();
    std::set<double, CustomComp(tol)> bbb;

        return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparator is passed as an argument to the set constructor:

```
std::set<double, CustomComp> bbb(CustomComp(tol));
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been reading on the std::set documentation, and the answer is right in front my eyes all these time. Somehow, my brain just didn't pick it up.